# Uploading files in a specific folder in googledrive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have used the following url to upload files to Googleddrive using curl in php

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media.
```

It' working fine to upload files in main outside folder i.e. drive.But How to upload files in a specific folder.I have folderid.

I tried following url to upload files in inner folders but it does not work:-

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/{folderid}?uploadType=media.
```

If anyone can help me.I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the id of the target folder in the parents collection in metadata:

```
{
  "title" : "My document",
  "mimeType" : "image/jpeg",
  "parents": [{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "<folderId>"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Claudio for your response.But I need your advice again.Actually I am using curl method for uploading files.So I m using the above mentioned url for uploading files.I tried the parents method to set the parents of the file, just uploaded by getting it's id.It works.But i think there should be some url like above for directly uploading files in a mentioned folderid bcoz by this method it first uploads file outside then it updates the file by getting the id of uploaded file and set it's parents and moves file from outside to it's parent folder.

Comment: "by this method it first uploads file outside then it updates the file by getting the id of uploaded file and set it's parents and moves file from outside to it's parent folder".

That's not true. Perhaps you misunderstood Claudio's suggestion.

Comment: Sorry Pinoyyid I think you misunderstood my point.By this method I mean curl method for uploading files.I use url to upload files(which is mentioned in asked question.That url uploads files outside).then take the id of that uploaded file and set it's parent folder and upddate() that file.Running update method it moves the file from outside folder to inside folder bcoz now parents are set.I hope now I am able to make my point clear.

Comment: You can do everything in a single call if instead of using simple upload (uploadType=media) you use multipart or resumable: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP for this? If so, then I will recommend using the PHP API client by Google as they do the heavy lifting for you.